# Stackblitz commit doesn't seem to update Github

Tags: stackblitz

According to [StackBlitz synchronization with github - upload to from StackBlitz to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062954/stackblitz-synchronization-with-github-upload-to-from-stackblitz-to-github/59685024#59685024) it is possible to commit from Stackblitz to Github.

But when I tried it doesn't seem to do so.  When I checked Github Repo I still have [my old Readme](https://github.com/grafcetonline/figma-plugin-savefile/blob/main/README.md) compared to the new one:

[image: new read me in editor]

Answer (score 0):

#### Update June 2023

1. If you have linked to a github repo and made changes locally in the editor, you should see a button on the top right to `Commit` your local changes

   [image: Commit button]
2. Which should pull up a dialog allow you to `Commit and Push`

   [image: Commit and push]
3. After which you should see a successful toast

   [image: Changes committed]

If any of these aren't working, it's possible there was a bug at the time you tried it, but appears to have been resolved as of June 2023